# Straight knife cut in perspective view?

Tags: modeling, topology, knife-tool

Here are the methods I use to make a straight cut

1. switch the view from perspective to orthographic
2. just make a cut then straighten it with s+x+0
3. shift+7 to align face to view then make a cut
4. use bisect tool then change the angle
5. vertex connect pressing J key and then straighten it

There are many other methods too but nothing is as fast as knife cut.

Is there any workaround to make straight cut in perspective view ?

I know we can snap knife tool to vertex & midpoint but it doesn't help in many cases.

Thank-you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: maybe an example image would help to understand some of those "many cases" where knife tool snapping doesn't help, but if I got what you mean, "loop cut" tools (ctrl-r) sometimes help, and also after cutting "snapped" knife cuts, you can "edge slide" (ctrl-e option) the new edge to another location...

Answer (score 2):

press "c" on the keyboard, then you can make 90 and 45 degree cuts, combine width ortographic view