# How to use knife tool properly?

Tags: knife-tool

I am new to blender.
Is there a way to make knife tool cut exactly along the axes? [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101253/straight-knife-cut-in-perspective-view

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27320/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-specific-angle-using-the-knife-tool/27664#27664 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/how-to-cut-a-mesh-by-specifying-the-angle/6895#6895